# How to set tooltip in TreeCellRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, renderer

I am stuck with setting a tooltip to one of my JPanel added to the node in a JTree. This question could be similar to [JTree node's changable tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082092/jtree-nodes-changable-tooltip) but not entirely.

I am also using JTree populated with some (custom) nodes. Each node contains a checkbox, a color box (JPanel) and node path. I am implementing TreeCellRenderer. I have not posted below code for what is being added to node as I think it is not necessary.

Below is part of my code:

```
    public class CheckTreeCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4025435851260573240L;

        CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel; 
        private TreeCellRenderer delegate; 
        TristateCheckBox checkBox = new TristateCheckBox();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        public CheckTreeCellRenderer(TreeCellRenderer delegate, CheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel){
            this.delegate = delegate;
            this.selectionModel = selectionModel;

            setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
            setOpaque(false); 
            checkBox.setOpaque(false);
        }

        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus){
            Component renderer = delegate.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            panel.setToolTipText("Hello");
            removeAll();
        add(checkBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(renderer, BorderLayout.EAST);

        return this;
    }
}
```

How to set a tooltip for JPanel added to a node?

Comment: *"I have not posted below code for what is being added to node as I think it is not necessary."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: As I mentioned I am adding three components to the node - a checkbox, a JPanel and a treenode path. But the fist two components are custom components so posting code for them here would be irrelevant and lengthy.

Comment: JComponent has the method setTooltipText. So you need to set the tooltip in getTreeCellRendererComponent method. Something like this.setToolTipText("It's a text");

Comment: Yes, I have written in the code sample above. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the docs of [JTree.getToolTipText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getToolTipText%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29):

> NOTE: For JTree to properly display tooltips of its renderers, JTree must be a registered component with the ToolTipManager. This can be done by invoking ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(tree). This is not done automatically!

This will fix it.